# Can we declare a static class inside a static function in java?

Tags: java, class, static

What is wrong with the bellow code?
And if something is wrong, please explain in detail with all the rules of static class and functions in java.

```
public class inner 
    {
        static class in
        {
            static void inclass()
            {
               static class infunclass
                {
                   static void fun()
                    {
                        System.out.println("Infunclass");
                    }
                }
                infunclass.fun();
            }
            static void infun()
            {
                System.out.println("Infun");
                inclass();
            }
        }    
        static void fun()
        {
            System.out.println("fun");
            in.infun();
        }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            fun();
        }
    }
```

Now when I remove the static keyword before the inclassfun, it showing a different error

```
public class inner 
{
    static class in
    {
        static void inclass()
        {
           class infunclass
            {
               static void fun()
                {
                    System.out.println("Infunclass");
                }
            }
           infunclass.fun();
        }
        static void infun()
        {
            System.out.println("Infun");
            inclass();
        }
    }    
    static void fun()
    {
        System.out.println("fun");
        in.infun();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        fun();
    }
}
```

static void fun()
^
modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations

Comment: `infunclass` is a local class. Local classes cannot be static... well, not in many Java versions until recently afaik

Comment: *please explain in detail with all the rules* These rules are explained many places, most authoritatively in the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we declare a static class inside a static function in java?

No.  The JLS forbids it.  The governing parts of the specification are as follows:

> "The modifier `static` pertains only to member classes (§8.5.1), not to top level or local or anonymous classes."   JLS 8.1.1

> "A *member class* is a class whose declaration is directly enclosed in the body of another class or interface declaration (§8.1.6, §9.1.4). "  JLS 8.5

A class declared directly within a method is a *local class*, not a *member class*